ECDSA without field inversion during verification
I am looking into ECDSA lately. Shooting from the hip here, but...
ECDSA currently signs as $(r,s)$ where:

$R\gets g^k$ for uniform $k\in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus\{0\}$.
$r \gets f(R)$

$f(R)$ is the ECDSA conversion function that parses $R$ as $(x,y)\in\mathbb{F}_q^2$ and returns $\bar{x} \bmod p$, where $\bar{x}$ is the integer representation of $x$.


$s \gets k^{-1}(H(m) + \mathsf{sk}\cdot r) \bmod p$

To verify, ECDSA's main check is:

assert $r \stackrel{?}{=} f((g^{H(m)} \mathsf{pk}^r)^{s^{-1}})$

An unnecessary, although small performance issue I see: Verification requires inverting $s$, which is one of the slowest field operations. (Yes, when batch-verifying a bunch of signatures, batch inversion ameliorates this.)
But there seems to be a simpler (equivalent?) ECDSA variant that does not have this problem: if we change signing to instead output $s'\gets k(e+\mathsf{sk}\cdot r)^{-1}$ (i.e., $s' = s^{-1}$), then verification would just be $r\stackrel{?}{=} f((g^{H(m)} \mathsf{pk}^r)^{s'})$.
Note that an ECDSA signature $(r,s)$ can be transformed into this $(r,s^{-1})$ modified variant (and viceversa). So a forgery on this scheme implies a forgery on ECDSA.
My question: How come this variant is not what's standardized in [JMV01] and used in practice? (I may be missing something obvious here.)
[JMV01]: The Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA); by Johnson, Don and Menezes, Alfred and Vanstone, Scott; in International Journal of Information Security; 2001; https://doi.org/10.1007/s102070100002

A detail: we should change the test $s\ne0$ in ECDSA signature production to (using the question's notation) $H(m)+\mathsf{sk}\cdot r\not\equiv 0\pmod p$.
The EUF-CMA security of the proposed variation is tightly equivalent to that of ECDSA: it's easy to turn any attack against one scheme into an attack of the other by inserting inversions modulo $p$.

How come this variant is not what's standardized

The direct reason is certainly precedence: ECDSA is a minimal adaptation of DSA giving improved performance and smaller public key. Almost only the group and function $f$ was changed. BTW, during that change, the function $k\mapsto f(g^k)$ ceased to be collision-resistant (notice $f(g^k)=f(g^{-k})$ in ECDSA), and thus ECDSA lacks the sEUF-CMA property of DSA.
However the question's variation of moving the inversion to the signer side, saving that computational overhead with no apparent drawback on the signer side, would also have applied to DSA, so we have to look for other reasons.
Precedence also applies to DSA. It's a close cousin of ElGamal's signature, which signing operation produces the $s$ of it's signature as $s\gets k^{-1}(H(m)-\mathsf{sk}\cdot r)\bmod(p-1)$, very similar to (EC)DSA.
However DSA was a radical departure from ElGamal signature, including requiring added modular inversion at either signing or verification, thus adding it on signature or verification was a design choice.
One possible reason to add it on verification is to get the lowest possible minimum delay between availability of $m$ and production of the signature: notice that in normal (EC)DSA a signing device can prepare $k$, then $r$ and $k^{-1}$ in advance of availability of $m$, and the delay for signature production is a hash, two multiplications and one addition modulo $p$, but no modular inversion. In some contexts (e.g. signing a transaction by a Smart Card requiring PIN entry), that possibility to perform part of the signature in masked time is quite real. In that context, the verifying device is much more powerful, thus the inversion on it's side is a marginal issue.
Intellectual property considerations may have played a role: perhaps (this is disputed) the designers of DSA wanted their design to stand as different as possible from the claims of Claus-Peter Schnorr's patents [Sc89a], [Sc90a], [Sc90b]. These describe a signature scheme using groups allowing a much smaller signature and faster operation than the earlier ElGamal signature, and DSA uses these Schnorr groups for the same reason. Schnorr's argumentation presented as an advantage the lack of modular inversion when there's one in ElGamal signature, thus having a modular inversion on each side made DSA farther from Schnorr's claims.
Also considerations on side channel attacks are different, but I'm not convinced that's decisively, or that it was that much of a design criteria in the design of DSA.

[Sc89a]: Claus-Peter Schnorr, Method for subscriber identification and for generation and verification of electronic signatures in a data exchange system, EP0383985 in European Patent Register, 1989;
[Sc90a]: id., Method for subscriber identification and for the generation and verification of electronic signatures in a data exchange system, EP0384475 in European Patent Register, 1990;
[Sc90b]: id., Method for identifying subscribers and for generating and verifying electronic signatures in a data exchange system, US Patent 4,995,082;

Hats off to you sir for such a comprehensive answer. The nuance on why faster pre-computed signing benefits mart-cards & the nuance on IP is very enligthening!
Thank you!
